# iPhone 5 crash after app store update

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, store

My applications update just entered the appstore. The problem is the application is crashing in iPhone 5, **it doesn't start**. I tested it in iPhone 4 and iPad and it is fine.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening, or why the update was accepted in the store?

It doesn't crash when running from the xcode.

Comment: You should try to get an iPhone 5 and test it properly, but just guessing that it is iPhone 5S instead of 5 I'll say may be related with the 64-bits.

Comment: Are apps crashing when a previous version was installed and used? Could be a CoreData issue for example, versioning related..

Comment: The app crashes by updating and by downloading. I'm not using CoreData...

Answer (score 2):

To reproduce your error install the previous version on your iPhone, then start the current version from xcode with debugging.

Sometimes such crashes happen for example when your previous version stored something in `NSUserDefaults` and your new version expects something different. Therefore it's very important to test the update scenario.

Comment: then why doesn't it crash in iPhone 4 / iPad?

Comment: @diogo.appDev Your error could be caused by anything. I can't answer you this question. But I gave you a way to find the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does accept applications that crash but do not crash very often. I have experienced several of my apps still crashing have been accepted by Apple. May be they don't test it comprehensively or they ignore some crashes that happen only when a certain functionality is targeted i.e don't crash too often.

Comment: Maybe they didn't update with the old version used.

Comment: it crashes in every iPhone 5, every time.

Comment: @diogo.appDev then it is a huge concern that they have accepted an application that crashes every time. May be they din't test it on any iphone5

Comment: At times, I have noticed that the updates to applications get accepted much more leniently then the first post of the application although Apple says that they check each update as it's a new app. btw you should upload a new version without crashes immediately so you don't get negative reviews

Comment: It doesn't crash when running from the mac...

Comment: Can you specify any special code or location where it crashes?

Comment: It crashes while in the splashscreen. And I can't replicate it, cause it runs fine from the xcode